# infinite loop when try to using iframe in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I am trying to use iframe to show pdf file in react. When I use iframe tag, it results in an infinite loop. Why dose this happen? how to fix this.Thanks.
Here is the code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe src="./assets/files/time.pdf" width="80%" height="100%">
         Download the PDF<a href="/index.pdf">Download PDF</a>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I got the following results like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr25o.png)

Comment: the code works fine in plain HTML, as showed in the following link
https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1087